# Cross Compilation error can't load library 'libc.so.6'

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, libc, uclibc, uclinux

I am trying to implement a dynamic library(`liblog.so`) which is going to run on i386 controller.

when i compile that in `Host Machine (Ubuntu Machine)` it compiles and generates the `.so` file successfully.
`liblog.so` is the the file which is put under `/usr/lib` in target machine.

```
merom@arunkumar:~/freedcs/freedcs-code1/Controller/src/Controller$ ldd log_client
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7707000)
    libnative.so.3 => not found
    libxenomai.so.0 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb76cd000)
    librt.so.0 => not found
    liblog.so => /usr/lib/liblog.so (0xb76c9000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0xb751e000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0xb74c7000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb74a9000)
    libc.so.0 => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb72f5000)
    /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0 => /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7708000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb72f0000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb72d7000)
merom@arunkumar:~/freedcs/freedcs-code1/Controller/src/Controller$
```

output at host machine.

Output at target machine:

```
libnative.so.3 => /usr/lib/libnative.so.3 (0xb78d9000)
libxenomai.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxenomai.so.0 (0xb78d4000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xb78c1000)
librt.so.0 => /lib/librt.so.0 (0xb78bd000)
liblog.so => /lib/liblog.so (0xb78b9000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0xb7793000)
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0xb7752000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb7748000)
libc.so.0 => /lib/libc.so.0 (0xb770a000)
libdl.so.0 => /lib/libdl.so.0 (0xb7706000)
libc.so.6 => not found
ld-uClibc.so.0 => /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0 (0xb78e2000)
```

when i send it to Target machine(Currently in VMware), when i run the `.\log_client` it shows `can't load library 'libc.so.6'` 
Yes i compiled `log_client` with linked with `liblog.so`

Compilation Commands

**Generating `liblog.so`**

`../../../../build/i386/buildroot-2011.11/output/host/usr/bin/i686-unknown-linux-uclibc-gcc -c log.c -o liblog.o`

`../../../../build/i386/buildroot-2011.11/output/host/usr/bin/i686-unknown-linux-uclibc-gcc  -Wcast-align -g -W -Wall -L../../../../build/i386/buildroot-2011.11/output/target/usr/lib -lxenomai -lpthread -lrt -shared -o liblog.so liblog.o -rdynamic -lcrypto -lssl`

**Generating `log_client`**

`cp liblog.so ../../../../build/i386/buildroot-2011.11/output/target/usr/lib`

`../../../../build/i386/buildroot-2011.11/output/host/usr/bin/i686-unknown-linux-uclibc-gcc  -Wcast-align -g -W -Wall -c log_client.c`

`../../../../build/i386/buildroot-2011.11/output/host/usr/bin/i686-unknown-linux-uclibc-gcc  -Wcast-align -g -W -Wall -L../../../../build/i386/buildroot-2011.11/output/target/usr/lib -lxenomai -lpthread -lrt -o log_client log_client.o -llog -rdynamic -lcrypto -lssl`

I am using same procedure for an other code that is working, though that code doesn't use this customized library(`liblog.so`), there were warnings too but i didn't posted here.
Please help me, i am frustrated!!

------------**Edited**----------

`file` Output

```
$ file liblog.so 
liblog.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped

$ file log_client 
log_client: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
```

------------**Update**----------

Some one suggested me use `--sysroot` while compiling the files, but even that didn't helped me. Same error coming out. :(

**I had put `sysroot` path to target machine's GCC's sysroot path**

**Generating `liblog.so`**

`../../../../build/i386/buildroot-2011.11/output/host/usr/bin/i686-unknown-linux-uclibc-gcc  -Wcast-align -g -W -Wall  -c log.c -o liblog.o --sysroot=/home/merom/freedcs/build/i386/buildroot-2011.11/output/host/usr/i686-unknown-linux-uclibc/sysroot/`

`../../../../build/i386/buildroot-2011.11/output/host/usr/bin/i686-unknown-linux-uclibc-gcc  -Wcast-align -g -W -Wall  -L../../../../build/i386/buildroot-2011.11/output/target/usr/lib -lxenomai -lpthread -lrt -shared -o liblog.so liblog.o -rdynamic -lcrypto -lssl --sysroot=/home/merom/freedcs/build/i386/buildroot-2011.11/output/host/usr/i686-unknown-linux-uclibc/sysroot/`

**Generating `log_client`**

`cp liblog.so ../../../../build/i386/buildroot-2011.11/output/target/usr/lib`

`../../../../build/i386/buildroot-2011.11/output/host/usr/bin/i686-unknown-linux-uclibc-gcc  -Wcast-align -g -W -Wall  -c log_client.c --sysroot=/home/merom/freedcs/build/i386/buildroot-2011.11/output/host/usr/i686-unknown-linux-uclibc/sysroot/`

`../../../../build/i386/buildroot-2011.11/output/host/usr/bin/i686-unknown-linux-uclibc-gcc -Wcast-align -g -W -Wall  -L../../../../build/i386/buildroot-2011.11/output/target/usr/lib -lxenomai -lpthread -lrt -o log_client log_client.o -llog -rdynamic -lcrypto -lssl  --sysroot=/home/merom/freedcs/build/i386/buildroot-2011.11/output/host/usr/i686-unknown-linux-uclibc/sysroot/`

**Update**

After Running objdump This was the output.

```
objdump -x log_client | grep NEEDED
NEEDED               libnative.so.3
NEEDED               libxenomai.so.0
NEEDED               libpthread.so.0
NEEDED               librt.so.0
NEEDED               liblog.so
NEEDED               libcrypto.so.1.0.0
NEEDED               libssl.so.1.0.0
NEEDED               libgcc_s.so.1
NEEDED               libc.so.0



objdump -x liblog.so | grep NEEDED
NEEDED               libnative.so.3
NEEDED               libxenomai.so.0
NEEDED               libpthread.so.0
NEEDED               librt.so.0
NEEDED               libcrypto.so.1.0.0
NEEDED               libssl.so.1.0.0
NEEDED               libgcc_s.so.1
NEEDED               libc.so.0
```

Comment: check whether host and target machines are of 32-bit or not

Comment: My target OS and CPU is 32 BIT, But Host machine is 64 bit and it's OS is 32(Ubuntu)

Comment: so make the .so file on target machine itself, as target machine cannot load 64 bit .so file as it is a 32-bit.

Comment: which `.so` file `liblog.so` or `libc.so.6`. As expected this dependency  of requiring `libc.so.6` shouldn't come, and i copied `liblog.so`to target machine.

Comment: The weirdest thing, IMO, is that reference to `libc.so.0`. I'm guessing that you have a file/symlink with that name somewhere that should not be there.

Comment: Sorry @rodrigo i don't understood the word `IMO`, suggest me how can i find which part of the code might referring to `libc.so.6`, i am frustrated with this problem.

Comment: @Merom: IMO=In My Opinion. Command `ldd` lists all the dependencies recursively, you can use instead this command: `objdump -x <file> | grep NEEDED` to see the individual dependencies of each library until you find the ones that depend on `libc.so.6` and/or `libc.so.0`. Probably, there will be your problem.

Comment: @rodrigo needed file is `libc.so.0` not `libc.so.6` so why this is showing the error.

Comment: @Merom: It is difficult to say. I'm guessing that you are mixing native and cross-compiler libraries. Try running the `NEEDED` check on every library listed in the `ldd` output to see which one references `libc.so.6`. As a last resort you can run `grep -l libc.so.6 /lib/* /usr/lib/*`, but that's not very trustworthy.

Comment: WTF now it's working, the only thing i did is i moved `liblog.so` to `/lib` from `/usr/lib` but in `PATH_ENVIORNMENT` `/usr/lib` also included !! :) yoho Thanx @rodrigo

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with an executable. Every tool I tried - ldd, objdump, readelf, strings - indicated depencency with libc.so.0, rather than .6. It turned out that one of its dependent libraries was depending on .6. So I went and fixed that and everything is working now.

The library had the wrong version because it was compiled using the wrong cross-compiler (I used it by mistake), so I recompiled and reuploaded it.